# Logout file works on localhost but not on iPage

Tags: php, server, localhost, hosting, logout

My logout file works on my localhost, but when I try to use it on my iPage hosting account, it keeps the session saved. I tested it by printing the session variable on the page which the login redirects to.

The code of my logout.php file is:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

Any help? Thank you

Comment: You mean `session_destroy()` is not working ?

Comment: Yes. The session remains active.

Comment: What happens if you do `session_destroy();var_dump($_SESSION);` ?

Answer (score 0):

After using `session_destroy();` the values in $_SESSION may still be available, but they will not be on the next page load.

```
$_SESSION = array(); // Destroy the variables.
```